# Any easy way to get grouped box plot using plotly and cufflinks?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I now that for scatter plot, you can write something like

```
df.iplot(kind='scatter', x='myX',y='myY',categories='myGroup')
```

supposing that `df` is a dataframe with those variables. 
However, this won't work if I change to

```
df.iplot(kind='box', x='myX',y='myY',categories='myGroup')
```

it will end up with a scatter plot. Is the `categories` setting not supported in box plot yet or I missed something?

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for that solution too, but could not find any help. But I was able to find a hack; For example in case of popular titanic data set from kaggle. Box plot of age by passenger class:

```
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()

box_age = train[['Pclass', 'Age']]
box_age.pivot(columns='Pclass', values='Age').iplot(kind='box')
```

You can do it in one step but in two (or three step by storing the pivot table in a object) step code looks clean. So Second step I am pivoting the data. So there will be 1 **non-null** value per rows. iplot can take care about the null values. I have tested with seaborn and iplot the give me the same answer. So its reliable. In case if you want to try both. Here is seaborn code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 7))
sns.boxplot(x='Pclass', y='Age', data=train, palette='winter')
```

**Note: I am using Jupyter Notebook that's why there is `%matplotlib inline`**